# Android SDK emulator not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-emulator

I asked this question a couple of days ago:

[Universal screen resolutions in Unity for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054680/universal-screen-resolutions-in-unity-for-android/33057444#33057444)

I have now made improvements, but I no longer have the devices to test on. The Android SDK has an emulator, but when I launch it there is only a black screen, however there are no errors. My question is how do I launch properly, or is there a better emulator to test a game on multiple devices?

I am developing within Unity.

Answer (score 0):

When you configured the emulator did you turn on the GPU?  There is a check box at the bottom of the configuration that says "Use Host GPU".  Turn that on and see if your situation improves.  With it turned off, the refresh rates are usually terrible on the android emulators (e.g. those created in the AVD Manager).  When you turn on the GPU, make sure you do not have the check box next to it, titled "snapshot" also turned on because you can't use both options simultaneously.

As for other emulators I am aware of 3 options.  The Visual Studio Emulator for Android is not bad, but for Unity work it is probably not a solid candidate as it doesn't currently support GPU operations or Google Play Services (not sure if you need that or not).  There's the Xamarin Android Player (which I've never used), and there's the Genymotion emulator which is what most full time Android developers swear by, but it isn't free (though it's also not very expensive).

Comment: Hi @Bruce Van Horn ! I was just testing out the visual studio emulator for android and got the very popular black empty screen problem, which is being solved by turning on or off "Use Host GPU". I read your statement about the GPU operations not supported and decided to check, and it appears that it's true indeed. The introduction [link] (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx) shows exactly an example from Unity on the Screenshot part. Wondering what does it mean? Is it supposed to work?